# Android- Unconventional Keyboard, change text on a key

Tags: android, keyboard, ime, android-input-method

I'm trying to develop an unconventional keyboard, I need to change the text in a key, depending on the combination of other keys pressed. 
Like Candidates View but inside the keyboard, in one key.

I wonder if I can change the text on a key , or if I can use a different layout to the Keyboard XML.

my keyboard is based on the Soft Keyboard app example and can be referred to at this [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard/src/com/example/android/softkeyboard/SoftKeyboard.java) .

Comment: Is this keyboard for all apps, or only for your app?

Comment: is for all apps, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Tags](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag()) for your View, so you can use the setTag/getTag mechanism when pressing it..

```
private final View.OnClickListener myListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getTag() != null) {
                if (v.getTag() instanceof String) {
                    getCurrentInputConnection().commitText((String) v.getTag(), 1);
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "(v.getTag() instanceof String) == false");
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "(v.getTag() != null) == false");
            }
        }
    };
```

And the XML example of a key:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/aButton_N"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:tag="n"
        android:text="n"
        android:onClick="myListener"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />
```

An example of alteration:

```
Button myBt = (Button) findViewWithTag("n");
myBt.setTag("N");
```

For all other purposes, remember that the "KeyboardView" is a facilitator. In your View, you can add any `child` of a `View`, so Buttons, ImageViews etc will work.

If you need the "image" (the Bitmap) that the KeyboardView uses, then you can "redrawn" (by overriding the `onDrawn()` function) of your keyboard, and make any alteration needed for keys or its layout...

Do note, that Keyboard, Keyboard.Key, etc. are all facilitators, for speed, low memory usage, and draw "easiness", by altering the layout, you can use anything with it, so ScrollViews / LinearLayouts / Framelayouts can greatly simplify your program/Views, but they use a bit more memory, check if your program can make this choice.

### Edit:

A `Button` object, has several attributes. Its displaying text is a `String`, use `button.getText().toString()` to fetch it. A Tag, is a "pointer" to an `Object` of any kind.... if you want to writte the current text of the button, and use another related system, you can use the following:

```
private final View.OnClickListener myListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Button thisButton = (Button) v;
           getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(thisButton.getText().toString(), 1);
        }
    };
```

And to change the "content" of the button:

```
Button aButton = (Button) findViewById(YOUR.ID.HERE);
aButton.setText("a new long string to replace the old value.");
```

And sorry for bad english, if something is hard to understand, please, let me know

Comment: Thanks, I have not been able to use TAG within the xml "qwerty" as you say in Button, in your example. I need change the parameter (android:keyLabel="a") with another string, from my code. This is why i ask if i can use another layout than "qwerty". What can i do?. I have a bad english too.

Comment: @Ckst Please, review the answer, and check if it fits your needs. The TAG is the system I use, however, another simpler example can be used.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all keys like that

`List<Keyboard.Key> keys = mKeyboardView.getKeyboard().getKeys();`

By proper event you can change key's icon or label, check [Keyboard.Key](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `android:keyboardMode` available as part of `Keyboard.Row`, it selectively displays row based on the mode you are in. So you can create multiple modes with different rows (keys with different values and functions).

Here is the  [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Row.html#attr_android:keyboardMode) for reference.